# Using an asp page to set flags for sql or any way to avoid a sql injection

Tags: sql, asp-classic, sql-injection

I was wondering if it is possible to have my asp code set flags for my sql database? Although if you have a better suggestion for what to do to avoid a sql injection through the address bar I will take that too.

Comment: What do you mean by `set flags`?

Comment: I was looking some stuff up and found Trace Flags on msdn which seem to be prefect regarding what I need but from the look of it they need to be started on the DB. I was looking to make it more of an if statment which could be done with some work around on asp.

Comment: I will reply in the form of an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Basic steps to prevent sql injection attacks are:

1. Parametrize your queries; that is, do things like:

   insert into tables (column, colum2, column) values (?,?,?)

   And have your code pass parameters to the query.
2. Use stored procedures if you can, and fit well your situation (with one caveat - 3rd point below).
3. If you use stored procs, don't use dynamic SQL inside them or that will expose you again to sql injection attacks. What I mean by that is to avoid concatenating strings inside the stored proc in order to construct your statements.
4. Validate user input (both, client **and** server side - never trust javascript validation)

I think following those 4 points will make your application immune to sql injection attacks.

I recommend you also read the article posted by jdavies below. It gives some additional useful information.

Comment: Ive tired all this but like I said I'm getting hit on them adding .asp?sqlcode to the end of my address.

Comment: If you are doing all of the above, there's nothing to worry about. They can die trying and they won't break your app. You can relax. If you want to block them, perhaps you can put a filter on your firewall or have some other defense mechanism but I wouldn't worry about SQL injection in particular.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following Microsoft article, which discusses exactly what you require, in depth and for different data access strategies.

[How To: Protect From SQL Injection in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx)